# Haskell - Couldn't match type [] with IO

Tags: haskell, types, match, program-entry-point, quicksort

I am new at Haskell. Why am I getting the error message

> (Couldn't match type '[]' with 'IO' — Haskell) in folowing code.

In main I only need time of algorithm running without the result.

Only want to measure algorithm time.

```
qsort1 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qsort1 []     = []
qsort1 (p:xs) = qsort1 lesser ++ [p] ++ qsort1 greater
    where
        lesser  = [ y | y <- xs, y < p ]
        greater = [ y | y <- xs, y >= p ]

main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    qsort1 (take 1000000 $ randomRs (1, 100000) (mkStdGen 42))
    end <- getCurrentTime
    print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `main` function isn't right. Unless `qsort1` is an `IO` action you cannot perform it in an IO monad. Instead you can put it in the let binding:

```
main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    let x = qsort1 (take 1000000 $ randomRs ((1 :: Int), 100000) (mkStdGen 42))
    end <- getCurrentTime
    print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

Also note that I have explicitly given a type annotation for `1` to avoid some compile errors.

But that being said you cannot actually find the the total time taken to do the sorting because of lazy evaluation. `x` will never be computed because it's never used in the program. If you run `main`, it give you this output which is definetly wrong:

```
λ> main
0.000001s
```

Instead you can use this to calculate the computation:

```
main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    let x = qsort1 (take 1000000 $ randomRs ((1 :: Int), 100000) (mkStdGen 42))
    print x
    end <- getCurrentTime
    print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

<s>Instead of printing, you can also use the `BangPatterns` extension to force the computation of `qsort1`:</s>

```
main = do
    start <- getCurrentTime
    let !x = qsort1 (take 1000000 $ randomRs ((1 :: Int), 100000) (mkStdGen 42))
    end <- getCurrentTime
    print (diffUTCTime end start)
```

`BangPatterns` will not lead to full evaluation as @kosmikus points out. Instead use a library like `criterion` which has been specially made for benchnmarking.

Comment: Thank YOU. Problem is that now i dont get time of algorithm but time of algorithm and time of printing.

Comment: @MatejKr I have updated the answer to not use printing and instead force the computation using Bang operator.

Comment: Why do I get illegal bang-pattern (use BangPattern). I am a new guy at haskell Thanks

Comment: @MatejKr Put `{-#LANGUAGE BangPatterns#-}` on top of your file.

Comment: The bang pattern is not correct here. It will not force full evaluation, and not lead to the correct result. Just use something like criterion for benchmarking rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Could you be more specific. I am new to Haskell and don't know how to do it. Thanks

Comment: @kosmikus Why `BangPatterns` will not lead to full evaluation here ? Although I accepth that criterion should be used for benchmarking. @MatejKr It's an Haskell library used for Benchmarking.

Comment: Because bang patterns generally do not cause full evaluation, but only evaluate to weak head normal form. And qsort1 returns  a list.

Answer (score 0):

I used method below and it works fine:

```
main = do
        let arr = take 1000000 $ randomRs ((1 :: Int), 10000000) (mkStdGen 59)
        defaultMain [
          bgroup "qs" [ bench "1"  $ nf quickSort arr ]
          ]
```